# quiero poner estas 2 variables en los dos parametros con metodo get en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Como envió 2 datos desde 2 selects diferentes por medio de la route en laravel, el name de el primer select y el name del segundo select

aqui tengo las variables que se llaman var1 y var2 que son os name que estan en los select y las quiero llevar por método get con los parametros id y id2 y nos da error, llegan las 2 varibales en la url, pero pasan de alli.

```
    `<form action="{{route('comparacion.index', ['id'=>'var1','id2'=>'var2'])}}" 
    method="GET">
                    <select name="var1">
                        @foreach ($producto as $item)
                            <option value="{{$item->id_catalogo}}">{{$item- 
   >id_catalogo}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <select name="var2">
                        @foreach ($producto as $item)
                            <option value="{{$item->id_catalogo}}">{{$item- 
   >id_catalogo}}</option>`introducir el código aquí`
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Comparar">
                </form>
    
    Route::get('comparacion/{id}/{id2}', [ComparacionController::class, 'index'])
        ->name('comparacion.index');`
```

Comment: Lo ideal sería que los `value` de tus `option` fueran diferentes ya que ahorita tienes los 2 a la misma variable `$item->id_catalogo` y al tener dos variables diferentes podrías utilizarlas también en el `form action`

Comment: hey muchas gracias ya lo pude solucionar